# Android Paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND) performance issues

Tags: android, canvas, android-custom-view

I have a Paint object initialized in the following way:

```
chartLinePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
chartLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
chartLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(6.0f);
chartLinePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
```

The problem is that drawing large amounts of lines with this paint causes significant frame drops:

```
canvas.drawLines(pts, chartLinePaint);
```

Removing `chartLinePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND)` brings the perfomance back to normal, but the line connections are not smooth.

Another option I tried was using `Canvas.drawPath`, but the performance is even worse than `Canvas.drawLines`.

Without `setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND)` (frame drawing time us under 16ms):

[image]

With `setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND)` (frame drawing time significantly exceeds 16ms):

[image]

Comment: What is the refresh rate of the line? (example: you update one line with a new coordinate every 1 second or so?)

Comment: @MatPag I'm just drawing lines with Canvas.drawLines once and then just scrolling the parent ScollView container. So onDraw is only called when I scroll the parent view.

Comment: Can you share the custom view code? (just with fixed coordinates).